# telegram bot | detect if user sent a message from mobile or desktop

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I currently made bot with `node-telegram-bot-api` and a issue I face was I used emojis on a few messages the bot sends and realised few emojis of them are not supported in desktop. Can I detect if user sending message to my bot is in desktop so that I can alternate the replies accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer for this is No. There's no way of detecting what platform the user on the other side is on in neither Bot API nor MTProto API.

Answer (score 1):

No, There is no possibility to get user Device Name.

Check User Object: (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#user)
Check Chat Object: (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat)
CHeck Message Object: (https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message)